# Wide angle lens for Raspberry Pi v2 camera

Tags: picamera

I am looking for adding a wide angle lens to the Raspberry Pi v2 camera. Googling helped me locate a 3D printed lens holder and lens that I can attach to the v2 camera. Now I have the M12 lens and the M12 lens holder. I am not sure how to proceed further. Should I remove the existing lens on the Raspberry Pi camera?

I tried adding the M12 lens and holder to the camera gives me blurry images.

M12 mount: [M12 mount for Raspberry Pi V2 Camera](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1963856)

M12 lens set: [M12 Lens Set with IR Cut Filter (8/6/3/2.65mm)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01LZQ9UHN)

Comment: FYI an easy way to find lenses without looking at a dozen different catalogs is this [free lens search tool](https://www.opticsforhire.com/lens-search)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [comments section](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1963856/comments) of the lensholder at Thingiverse one has to remove the PiCamera's lens. Note that removing the lens makes the camera susceptible to dust and damage. Be extra careful with the open sensor.

> tracyaf_2
>   Aug 31, 2017
>
> This works excellent. FYI you will have to take out the existing Pi Camera Lens

and

> vaqueram - in reply to GaugeTheory
>   Feb 14, 2018
>
> Yes, there is, you'll have to remove it. Its not the easiest thing in the world, but its completely doable. 
>   I would recommend you print a Pi camera lens spanner, such as this one : https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:1574661
>   You print two of these, one to hold the body, the other to unscrew the lens.
>
> Be careful though, once you remove the lense, the CMOS sensor is completely unprotected and vulnerable to even the smallest speck of dust.

Further reading on "de-caping" the PiCamera:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=148929

Comment: I am confused.  Why not buy a wid angle lens? https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-raspberry-pi-camera-wide-angle-lens.html
https://www.google.com/search?q=%E6%A0%91%E8%8E%93%E6%B4%BE%E5%B9%BF%E8%A7%92%E6%91%84%E5%83%8F%E5%A4%B4&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzgqnb94HiAhXCF4gKHVv6Cs8Q_AUIDigB&biw=1342&bih=695

Comment: @tlfong01 what can I say? Not more than that is just not what the OP asked for?

Comment: Thank for your reply.  Your double negative statement confuses mea bit.  Let me translate it to something like this - "I cannot say more than the OP asks".  I remember one year ago when I first joined this Q&A site, many of my answers were told to be irrelevant, or out of topic.  If this is Rpi SE's policy, I fully agree with you.

Comment: @tlfong01 I fail to get your point. The OP asks how to use a M12 lens (that he already purchased) with a M12 lensholder (that he already printed) and the PiCam, more specifically if he needs to remove the original lens. This is what my answer addresses. Obviously your alternative to use a wide angle lens that directly fits the PiCam would be another way to go. There is likely no harm in including that alternative as part of this answer or have another user post another answer. If you ask why did I not include that option, the answer is simple: I did not think of it in the first place.

Comment: @Ghanima If there is a wide-angle lens I can use with the pi cam v2, kindly let me know of it.  It will save me of the headache of having to print and fit the m12 lens holder.